# Efficient to do math in a MySql "order by" clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I've been told on several occasions that it is quite efficient to SELECT using math and that it is NOT very efficient to use math in a WHERE clause.  Are these sentiments correct?  And how does this apply to ORDER BY clauses?

Thanks!!

Example:

```
SELECT a.* FROM a ORDER BY (a.field_1*a.field_2)
```

Comment: I would *imagine* a computed value invalidates any index used for ordering (if there was a potential candidate to begin with) .. what do the query plans of your test-cases show?

Comment: In this particular example it almost doesn't matter - you'll have a fullscan anyway

Comment: Yes it does matter.  If you use the ORDER BY you scan the table, stuff all the results into sort buffers, and sort repeatedly if the sort buffer is too small to hold all the rows from the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query will have to sort the entire table using temporary files on disk if the result is larger than the sort_buffer_size.

You probably want to add a column to your table that holds the value of field1*field2.  This of course slightly denormalizes your data, BUT YOU CAN CREATE AN INDEX ON THE FIELD.

If you have an index on the new field, then MySQL can read the data pre-sorted using the index, because MySQL indexes are b*tree structures and b*tree structures are stored in pre-sorted order.  This won't incur extra disk IO or CPU activity for the sort and you will scan the table only once.

Comment: BTW, if you were using Oracle you could create a function based index on field_1 * field_2, but MySQL doesn't support that.

Comment: Dang... a function based index would be amazing.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Its a good idea , but I never think that using mathematical function in `ORDER BY` clause make any sense.

You can use this by alias :-

```
select *,(intId * intId)as xalias from m_xxx_list order by xalias;
```

OR

```
select * from m_xxx_list order by (intId + intId);
```

Yes , If you are using mathemetical aggregate function of MYSQL, then Test it.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL to sort results by a computed value, it actually needs to calculate the value on the fly, after it has filtered out rows based on the `WHERE` clause. If the result set is quite large, then MySQL will need to compute the results for all the rows.

For a small result set, this should be fine. However, the larger your result set is (previous to the application of the `LIMIT`), then the more calculations the server has to do simply figure out the value to order the rows in. If the calculation is deterministic, then you should cache it in a column in the result set, and then index it. If it's on the fly, then you'll need to ensure your CPU is up to the task.

In the case provided, I would recommend creating a column, `a.field_3`, and store the result  of `(a.field_1*a.field_2)` in it. Whenever the values of `a.field_1` or `a.field_2` change, you'll need to recalculate the result.

Comment: You still have to add an index to the field or you will scan and sort the whole table regardless.  With the index, the database can read the rows in sorted order using the index without any extra sorting.  The cost of the sort is essentially amortized over the inserts into the table.